# Ambiguity of return values

Tags: c

In the C language book (by K&R), in the section on **low level I/O** , I came across two functions `read()` and `close()`  both of which have an integer return type. But I have seen that they are being used without even caring to assign the return value to any integer variable. But when I create a user defined function having integer return type and use it without assigning it to integer variable it causes compiler warning. Why this inconsistency?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Are you sure about "compile time error"? I am only used to seeing compiler warnings in that situation. Very important warnings, to be ignored at ones own risk, but only warnings nevertheless. Are you compiling with the same configurations in both cases? You can get most compilers to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: It is not uncommon for code not to check the return value from `close()`, mainly because there isn't much the program can do if `close()` fails. It can fail for a variety of reasons, but (if the file descriptor was valid and open) you have to assume that it is unusable even if the close fails. You might report that there were problems, but it often wouldn't affect the program much. Ignoring the return value from `read()` is much more problematic; there are not many circumstances where it is really valid. If you need to drain a pipe or terminal input queue, or similar, it might be OK, sort of.

Comment: In your code, you shouldn't have to assign the function result to a variable (though it is often a good idea to do so). You could simply use the result in an `if` condition, or a `switch` condition, or perhaps in a loop condition.  And even that isn't really required. You can cast the result to `void` to ignore it explicitly.  So, you need to show the code that causes a compilation error, and identify the compiler and platform and show the compiler options you're using. Few if any compilers will complain about your code calling a function that returns an `int` but ignoring the returned value.

Comment: You might be mixing up assigning a return value and returning a value from a non-void function. For the latter it is to be expected to get an error if you miss the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers traditionally don't warn for omitting the result of library function calls. Functions like `printf`, `scanf` and `memcpy` do return something, yet someone back in the dark ages of K&R decided to implicitly skip checking the result of the functions. It became de facto standard. Although to this day, skipping the result remains bad practice in many cases (like in the case of `scanf`).

Compilers do warn if you don't check the result of application functions though, because that's almost always a bug. If you deliberately don't want to check the result, you should write `(void) func();` to silence such warnings.

---

(Side note: `read` and `close` aren't standard C, but Unix API. Still they are library functions.)

Comment: Understood. Thankyou

Comment: I've never seen a compiler warn for not using the result of a function (unless it was marked with `__attribute__(warn_unused_result)` or similar).

Comment: @melpomene It is somewhat common, though I can't think of a specific example out of the blue. In the old days, Borland compilers were pretty notorious for not giving such warnings, and gcc has always been the same.